# Checking how an element gained focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events, onfocus

### Context

I have a backbone app with an event listener for focus events on a textarea. Backbone uses jQuery events, so core of my question centers around jQuery focus events.

### Question

Is there a way to tell how an element came into `focus`, be it by `click` or `tab`?

The behavior of how the cursor gets positioned needs to be handled differently between these two cases, however there doesn't seem to be a way to distinguish between the two offhand.

I could listen to `click` events, *however* will still need to listen to `focus` to capture tabbing - this will overlap with `click` event as it will also focus the textarea resulting in double events.

I may to rethink this entirely.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/tanakisota/1/edit?js,console,output)

```js
$('textarea')
  .focus(function(event){
    console.log('You focused me by' + event.type);
  // Here I wish I know if the focus came from a 'click' or 'tab' events
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input placeholder="focus me, then tab" type="text"><br>
        <textarea>Focus me via click.   Now try via tabbing.</textarea> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.onfocus()` listener can get called in a number of ways which makes it a tricky even to bind to.

- Click on element
- Tab or Shift-Tab to element
- jQuery programatic focus `$( "#target" ).focus();`
- Switching between programs, and refocusing the internet browser

There is no unique identifier in the onfocus event to determine how it came into focus.

From what I found it is best to be more explicit and listen to `click()` and `onkeyup()` events to handle unique behaviors between them and avoid unexpected function calls (like the browser is refocused).

`onkeyup()` is great for capturing tab events as the tab key will be released 'up' when tabbing in, but not when tabbing out.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yefoyudoke/1/edit?js,console,output)

```
$('textarea')
 .click(focusedBy)
 .keyup(checkTab);

function checkTab(event){
 if (event.keyCode === 9) {
  focusedBy(event);
 }
}

function focusedBy (event){
 console.log('You focused me by ' + event.type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need a combo of focus, click and blur events to determine the origin of "getting focus". click->set value, focus -> check if that clickvalue was set -> do what you must -> reset on blur. you might also want to be looking out for ontouchdown

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `clicked` variable on `mousedown`.

You'll need to `blur` the `textarea` on `mousedown` so that `focus` will will be triggered on `mouseup`:

```js
var clicked= false;

$('textarea')
  .focus(function(event) {
    if(clicked) {
      $('#status').html('clicked');
      clicked= false;
    }
    else {
      $('#status').html('tabbed');
    }
  })
  .mousedown(function(event) {
    clicked= true;
    $(this).blur();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input placeholder="focus me, then tab" type="text"><br>
  <textarea>Focus me via click.   Now try via tabbing.</textarea> 
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a scaling way to do it without rerouting events or simulating extra actions:

```
var targ=$('textarea');

targ.focus(function(event){
    console.log('You focused me by ' + targ.eventType);
  // Here I wish I know if the focus came from a 'click' or 'tab' events
  });

$("body").mousedown(function(e){
   targ.eventType="mouse";
 }).keydown(function(e){
   targ.eventType="keyboard";
 });
```

this uses the jQuery collection to store the last event type, which is set by document-wide handlers.

if you need to re-use this functionality on other input types, just add more selectors to *targ* and differentiate in the handler using *event.target*.

http://jsbin.com/ruqekequva/2/edit